# Need Automatic Rerendering of DxTabs in Blazor Application Using DevExpress Components

Tags: c#, blazor, devexpress, blazor-state-management

I'm facing an issue with rerendering dxTabs in my Blazor application using DevExpress components. Here's the scenario: I've set up a tabbed interface using the dxTabs component, and I require the tabs to rerender automatically whenever a specific state changes in my application. Specifically, I want the tabs to rerender whenever the state represented by the AppState.SelectedPlace property changes.

Here's how I've defined the **AppState **class to manage the **SelectedPlace **state:

```
public class AppState
{
    public Place SelectedPlace { get; private set; } = new Place
    {
        Name = "Tessttttt"
    };

    public event Action? OnChange;

    public void SetSelectedPlace(Place place)
    {
        SelectedPlace = place;
        OnChange?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

In my parent razor page, I have the following markup:

```
@AppState.SelectedPlace.Name
@* ---- Section: Tabs ---- *@
<DxTabs RenderMode="TabsRenderMode.Default">
    <DxTabPage @key="MyKey" Text="Osnovne nastavitve">
        <TabBasicSettings />
    </DxTabPage>
    <DxTabPage Text="IPoint">
        <TabIPoint />
    </DxTabPage>
    <DxTabPage Text="Dodatno">
        <TabAdditional />
    </DxTabPage>
</DxTabs>
@* ---- Section: Places Tree View ---- *@
<PlacesTreeView />
```

While the @AppState.SelectedPlace.Name rerenders successfully, the same property isn't being rerendered in the tabs group. Rerendering only occurs if I first change the @AppState.SelectedPlace state within  by clicking on another node and then navigate to another tab, and finally come back to the first one.

I'm seeking a solution to trigger the rerendering of the tabs whenever the state property changes without the need for the described workaround.

Comment: DevExpress is a paid for library, have you tried asking them?

Comment: I contacted them but no response yet.

Comment: NP - You're problem here will be finding an answerer who knows DevExpress.